# How do I get the IP address and port from a sniffed Wi-Fi packet?

Tags: wifi, packet-sniffers

For a completely legal and ethical purpose, I need to sniff a Wi-Fi packet while my station is not connected to a Wi-Fi network, and find the packet's destination IP and port.

Is it possible?

I see that there is a [MAC address information](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/wireless_lan/wlan_packets#wp1000999) in the packet, but [this article](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/how+to+find+MAC+and+IP+addresses+in+network+data+stream) claims IP address is in the packet either. On the other hand, I ran Wireshark but couldn't find an IP address in Wireshark dumps.

A packet sample:

```
me@zombie:~$ sudo tcpdump -qec1 -i mon1 -x
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on mon1, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 262144 bytes
19:19:12.623271 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11b -52dB signal antenna 3 BSSID:28:c6:8e:8a:b0:1e (oui Unknown) DA:Broadcast SA:28:c6:8e:8a:b0:1e (oui Unknown) Beacon (Branto) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5 11.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit] ESS CH: 1, PRIVACY
    0x0000:  83a1 fdba 8201 0000 6400 1104 0006 4272
    0x0010:  616e 746f 0108 8284 0b16 2430 486c 0301
    0x0020:  0105 0400 0200 002a 0100 2f01 0030 1401
    0x0030:  0000 0fac 0401 0000 0fac 0401 0000 0fac
    0x0040:  010d 0032 040c 1218 600b 0500 0027 0000
    0x0050:  2d1a bc19 17ff ff00 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0060:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 3d16 0108
    0x0070:  1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0080:  0000 0000 4a0e 1400 0a00 2c01 c800 1400
    0x0090:  0500 1900 7f08 0100 0800 0000 0040 dd31
    0x00a0:  0050 f204 104a 0001 1010 4400 0102 1047
    0x00b0:  0010 03e5 c4a4 0809 0079 5124 8592 3759
    0x00c0:  f1b6 103c 0001 0310 4900 0600 372a 0001
    0x00d0:  20dd 0900 1018 0200 000c 0000 dd18 0050
    0x00e0:  f202 0101 8c00 03a4 0000 27a4 0000 4243
    0x00f0:  5e00 6232 2f00
```

The LAN assigns addresses 10.0.1.x.

Comment: Post the packet content on your question, if it's too big, use pastebin.com

Comment: I will, when I get to that PC. Though, the question is about a generic packet structure: I need a mechanism that will work on most Wi-Fi networks. I cannot see how a specific packet will help. On the bright side, I can totally choose what kind of packet to send - for example, it could be SNMP. So any working option will do.